# React Native Clear Interval Not Stopping Interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Start elapsed ticker
    const levelTicker = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("TICK...");
      if (getCurrentTournament() != null) {
        setFormattedLevelTimer(
          moment
            .utc(
              new Date(getCurrentTournament().levelEnds).getTime() - getTime()
            )
            .format("mm:ss")
        );
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(levelTicker);
    };
  }, []);
```

When I leave the component, the ticker never stops and throws a Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component warning.

I changed clearInterval into a console.log and it prints correctly when changing components, but clearInterval is not clearing the interval.

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea why this has occurred, but after 3 hours of going over docs I came across this:

```
it's worth noting that the pool of ID's used by SetInterval() and setTimeout() are shared, which means you can technically use clearInterval() and clearTimeout() interchangeably.
```

I switched from `clearInterval()` to `clearTimeout()` and it seems to have successfully stopped the interval.